# Finding most recent startdate, and endDate from consecutive dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below:

| user_id | store_id | stock | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 116 | 2 | 0 | 2021-10-18 |
| 116 | 2 | 0 | 2021-10-19 |
| 116 | 2 | 0 | 2021-10-20 |
| 116 | 2 | 0 | 2021-08-16 |
| 116 | 2 | 0 | 2021-08-15 |
| 116 | 2 | 0 | 2021-07-04 |
| 116 | 2 | 0 | ,2021-07-03 |
| 389 | 2 | 0 | 2021-07-02 |
| 389 | 2 | 0 | 2021-07-01 |
| 389 | 2 | 0 | 2021-10-27 |
| 52 | 6 | 0 | 2021-10-28 |
| 52 | 6 | 0 | 2021-10-29 |
| 52 | 6 | 0 | 2021-10-30 |
| 116 | 38 | 0 | 2021-05-02 |
| 116 | 38 | 0 | 2021-05-03 |
| 116 | 38 | 0 | 2021-05-04 |
| 116 | 38 | 0 | 2021-04-06 |

The table can have multiple consecutive days where a product ran out of stock, so I'd like to create a query with the last startDate and endDate where the product ran out of stock. For the table above, the results have to be:

| user_Id | store_id | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 116 | 2 | 2021-10-18 | 2021-10-20 |
| 116 | 38 | 2021-05-02 | 2021-05-04 |
| 389 | 2 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-02 |
| 52 | 6 | 2021-10-28 | 2021-10-30 |

I have tried the solution with row_number(), but it didn't work. Does someone have a tip or idea to solve this problem with SQL (PostgreSQL)?

Comment: In your table you show `store_id` and in the results `warehouse_id`. They look to be the same, are they?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and make sure to include the query you tried, and which results that query produced.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 
thx, I have already edited the table

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it :

```
select user_id, store_id,min(date) startdate,max(date) enddate
from (
   select *, rank() over (partition by user_id, store_id order by grp desc) rn from (
       select *, date - row_number() over (partition by user_id,store_id order by date) * interval '1 day' grp
       from tablename 
) t) t where rn = 1
group by user_id, store_id,grp
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7b027fb453f56f7c88a9a0ab71743205)*

Comment: @OArmas you are welcome , please accept / upvote if this answer was helpful